# Groovy shorthand name access of stripping the verb and removing parentheses

Tags: groovy

In the Groovy documentation, it mentions shorthand notation for accessing properties just by name, for example, `obj.getFoo()` would be equivalent to `obj.foo`, and `obj.setFoo(val)` would be equivalent to `obj.foo = val`. It looks like this is also applicable to methods prefixed with "is". For example, with a `File` object, instead of doing `obj.isFile()`, you could do `obj.file`, and it would semantically be the same. Does this shorthand notation where you can strip the verb and not have parentheses apply to any other kinds of Groovy methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it so much as removing the verb and parentheses.  It's more like you're accessing the property directly, as you would in languages like Ruby and Python.  This is just Groovy being convenient and different from Java.  There are plenty of similar conveniences in the language like default operator overloading for collections (like "<<" and +) and "collection spreads" by using *.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Ruby and Python properties. I should clarify -- I don't think the Groovy documentation mentions property syntactic sugar working with methods other than getter/setters. So I was surprised to see it working for isFile(). Basically, I was wondering what other kinds of method signatures property syntactic sugar applies to other that "get", "set", and "is".

Comment: The reason they went with "is" is because it's a Java idiom.  Generally with boolean fields, the getter is prefixed with "is" rather than "get."  Just another nicety of the Groovy language!

Answer (score 1):

So it is really not like accessing the property directly OR stripping the verb.  It is syntactic sugar.

In Groovy:

```
println bob.name
```

Is equivalent in Java to:

```
System.out.println(bob.getName());
```

In Groovy:

```
bob.name = "Bob"
```

Is equivalent in Java to:

```
bob.setName("Bob");
```

Also, in Groovy, default implementations are provided without any code.  So where you might generate default getters and setters in Java, Groovy has those compiled into your class by default.

You can always override those by providing your own getter and setter so you are never accessing the property directly.

There is a great deal of information at the Groovy Language site.  Here is just one place where this is explained although more details can be found through the Groovy Language site.

http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, I understand properties. To clarify, I was more surprised to see this syntactic sugar work for methods prefixed with "is" such as isFile(), and so I was wondering how far this syntactic sugar covers apart from just properties.